# Lost / Forgotten Wallet?

Tags: wallet

I have this issue I have... When I first started using crypto currencys I used a lot of wallets ... etc trying to get a feel for what I wanted.. so ... Now I have a wallet that reads . 01 BTC balance and while I recognize the the last few letters of the address .. I have no clue what or where is it.. Evercoin, Crytonator, Coinbase... Any ideas .. I am sure I can find it if I had and clue where to look...

Answer (score 1):

If you were getting transaction notifications to your email address, you might be able to find something in your mail account. Other than that, an address alone does not provide any indication which service or software might have generated it.